# How do I see which version of Swift I'm using?

Tags: swift, xcode, terminal

I just created a new Swift project within Xcode. I am wondering which version of Swift it's using.

How can I see, in Xcode or the terminal, what version of Swift I am using inside my project?

Comment: Besides the title of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140476/how-can-i-programmatically-find-swifts-version%22 I find no **similarity** to this question that's enough to label this question as it's **duplicate**. The essence of this question is not how to find the version of Swift **programmatically**, but how to find the version of Swift in a **general** way (via terminal or Xcode or etc.). This is a big difference.

Answer (score 583, accepted):

Project build settings have a block 'Swift Compiler - Languages', which stores information about Swift Language Version in key-value format. It will show you all available (supported) Swift Language Version for your Xcode and active version also by a tick mark.

> Project ► (Select Your Project Target) ► Build Settings ► (Type
> 'swift_version' in the Search bar) Swift Compiler Language ► Swift Language
> Version ► Click on Language list to open it (and there will be a tick mark on any one of  list-item, that will be current swift version).

Look at this snapshot, for easy understanding:

[image: xcode with described areas highlighted]

---

With help of following code, programmatically you can find Swift version supported by your project.

```
#if swift(>=5.9)
print("Hello, Swift 5.9")

#elseif swift(>=5.8)
print("Hello, Swift 5.8")

#elseif swift(>=5.7)
print("Hello, Swift 5.7")

#elseif swift(>=5.6)
print("Hello, Swift 5.6")

#elseif swift(>=5.5)
print("Hello, Swift 5.5")

#elseif swift(>=5.4)
print("Hello, Swift 5.4")

#elseif swift(>=5.3)
print("Hello, Swift 5.3")

#elseif swift(>=5.2)
print("Hello, Swift 5.2")

#elseif swift(>=5.1)
print("Hello, Swift 5.1")

#elseif swift(>=5.0)
print("Hello, Swift 5.0")

#elseif swift(>=4.2)
print("Hello, Swift 4.2")

#elseif swift(>=4.1)
print("Hello, Swift 4.1")

#elseif swift(>=4.0)
print("Hello, Swift 4.0")

#elseif swift(>=3.2)
print("Hello, Swift 3.2")

#elseif swift(>=3.0)
print("Hello, Swift 3.0")

#elseif swift(>=2.2)
print("Hello, Swift 2.2")

#elseif swift(>=2.1)
print("Hello, Swift 2.1")

#elseif swift(>=2.0)
print("Hello, Swift 2.0")

#elseif swift(>=1.2)
print("Hello, Swift 1.2")

#elseif swift(>=1.1)
print("Hello, Swift 1.1")

#elseif swift(>=1.0)
print("Hello, Swift 1.0")

#endif
```

Here is result using Playground (with [Xcode 11.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-10-version-without-premium-developer-account?noredirect=1&lq=1))

[image]

Comment: I think this is correct answer. Easier than calling terminal. (especially if you have different version of Xcode installed)

Comment: This is the correct answer because swift version is configured on a per target basis.

Comment: I don't see this propoerty in my project with Xcode 8.1

Comment: you can see this property on latest versions of xcode

Comment: If you are using cocoa pods and downgrade swift this way you _might_ have to reinstall your pods for them to compile properly with the new swift version.

Comment: It the value is _Unspecified_, how can you tell what you're compiling against?

Comment: I could see this in Xcode 10.0. In 10.1, I can't find it anymore. Where did it go?

Comment: @JonMcClung - The same option is availble in Xcode 10.1 also. I just checked it.

Comment: @Krunal, yeah my bad. I was checking on the wrong project -- it was Objective-C based and didn't have any Swift code, so that's probably why.

Comment: What about when it says 'unspecified'?

Comment: @Mercutio - Can you please share your code, so we can check the issue. Almost we have covered all the versions of Swift there may not be such scope. Either you may be trying with Objective-C project.

Comment: I'm using this approach to make a table of which versions of Swift are supported by each version of Xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52819598/3939277

Comment: When I look in my project's build settings it shows 'Swift 5'. If I open a terminal and type 'swift -version' it returns 'Swift version 5.1.3' so using the terminal is giving more detailed information. I'm using Xcode version 11.3.1

Comment: For newbies like me, when XCode 11 looks a little different, note that you simply need to click on the project icon at the top of the file hierarchy on the left sidebar to view this Project UI, the blueprint icon with your project name above the folder containing your swift files. Then this info is easily accessible under `Swift Compiler - Language` (in `Swift Language Version`) in the Build Settings tab.

Comment: The max version is not precise there
xcrun swift -version is good one

Comment: This is helpful for editors and environments other than Xcode!

Comment: As of Oct 2, 2023...Xcode 14.3 prints Swift 5.8, Xcode 15.0 prints Swift 5.9. In case this helps anyone.

Answer (score 630):

What I do is say in the Terminal:

```
$ xcrun swift -version
```

Output for Xcode 6.3.2 is:

```
Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)
```

Of course that assumes that your `xcrun` is pointing at your copy of Xcode correctly. If, like me, you're juggling several versions of Xcode, that can be a worry! To make sure that it is, say

```
$ xcrun --find swift
```

and look at the path to Xcode that it shows you. For example:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/...
```

If that's your Xcode, then the output from `-version` is accurate. If you need to repoint `xcrun`, use the Command Line Tools pop-up menu in Xcode's Locations preference pane.

Comment: You can also use `xcode-select -p` to print the path to the Xcode that xcrun will use, and `sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/Xcode.app` to change it.

Comment: I just started to learn ios development and I am surprised that xcode does not let you choose the version of swift nor even let you know the version from GUI.

Comment: @RadekWilczak I don't know what you mean by "should be". I just copied the posted command and pasted into Terminal and hit Return, and it works. So maybe there's another alternative, but what I said isn't wrong.

Comment: This gave me the wrong answer.  Because swift is configured per target.  See the answer below from @Krunal for the best answer.

Comment: I agree with all the "the correct way is to set the SWIFT_VERSION" per project.  However, in earlier Xcode versions like 8.2, it doesn't state clearly in the UI what version of XCode is supported in the project, and just has "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" in the UI with Yes, No, unspecified.  The command line approach is extremely useful to be able to quickly query the answer to what is the max swift version available.

Answer (score 135):

**Open the Terminal and write:**

```
swift -version
```

Comment: This is not necessarily the version of swift that Xcode sees. Besides, you can have swift without having Xcode.

Answer (score 73):

From Xcode 8.3 onward `Build Settings` has key `Swift Language Version` with a value of swift version your target is using.

For older Xcodes use this solution,
open terminal and type following command(s)

**Case 1: You have installed only one Xcode App**

```
swift -version
```

**Case 2: You have installed multiple Xcode Apps**

- Switch `active developer directory` (Replace `Xcode_7.3.app` from
  following command with your Xcode app file name from *Application* directory for which you want
  to check swift version)

  ```
   sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_7.3.app/Contents/Developer
  ```
- Then

  ```
   swift -version
  ```

**NOTE:** From Xcode 8 to Xcode 8.2.x you can use swift 2.3 even though Xcode 8 uses swift 3.x as default swift version. To use swift 2.3, just turn on flag `Use Legacy Swift Language Version` to `YES` from `Build Setting` and XCode will use Swift 2.3 for that project target.

Answer (score 26):

You can see and select which Swift version Xcode is using in:

**Target** -> **Build Settings** -> **Swift Language Version**:

[image]

This is available in Xcode 8.3 and Xcode 9 (haven't checked older versions)

Comment: `Swift Language Version` doesn't come up as a setting in my Xcode 8.2.1 project. It does have `Use Legacy Swift Language Version`.

Comment: @ChrisPrince Yes, `Swift Language Version` didn't exist here in `Build Settings` until Xcode 8.3....  in prior Xcode 8.x versions `Use Legacy Swift Language Version`, `No` = Swift 3, and `Yes` = Swift 2.3

Comment: I only see the major version not the minor / patch components. e.g. right now I only see "Swift 5"

Answer (score 24):

To see the default version of swift installed on your machine then from the command line, type the following :

```
swift --version
```

> Apple Swift version 4.1.2 (swiftlang-902.0.54 clang-902.0.39.2)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0

This is most likely the version that is included in the app store version of Xcode that you have installed (unless you have changed it).

If you want to determine the actual version of Swift being used by a particular version of Xcode (a beta, for instance) then from the command line, invoke the swift binary within the Xcode bundle and pass it the parameter --version

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift --version
```

> Apple Swift version 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.0.16.7 clang-1000.10.25.3)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0

Answer (score 22):

In case anyone is looking for quick one-to-one mapping of Swift version based on Xcode Version:

```
Xcode 13.4.1 :      Swift version 5.6.1

Xcode 13.2   :      Swift version 5.5.2

Xcode 12.5   :      Swift version 5.4.2

Xcode 12.3   :      Swift version 5.3.2

Xcode 12.2   :      Swift version 5.3.1

Xcode 11.6   :      Swift version 5.2.4

Xcode 11.5   :      Swift version 5.2.4

Xcode 11.4   :      Swift version 5.2

Xcode 11.3   :      Swift version 5.1.3

Xcode 11.2.1 :      Swift version 5.1.2

Xcode 11.1   :      Swift version 5.1
```

Obtained with running following command as mentioned on different Xcode versions:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift --version
```

Answer (score 19):

This reddit post helped me:
https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/4o8atc/xcode_8_which_swift/d4anpet

> Xcode 8 uses Swift 3.0 as default. But you can turn on Swift 2.3. Go to project's Build Settings and set 'Use Legacy Swift Language Version' to YES.

Good old reddit :)

Comment: I can't find this by search 'Use Legacy Swift Language Version'   or 'Legacy'

Comment: I'm using latest Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) and swift 3 there in Swift Language Version. Now I want to change this to swift 2.3 but there is only one option swift 3.0 and 2nd is unspecified. so would you please guide how this would be possible ? to get swift 2.3 in my current project? @alexisSchreier

Answer (score 10):

```
/usr/bin/swiftc --version
```

and [swift version <--> Xcode version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Xcode&section=20#Latest_versions)

Answer (score 8):

Either you can run a command on terminal

```
xcrun swift -version
```

or

You can refer below table to check which Xcode is using which version of swift language.

```
Xcode 13.4.1 :      Swift version 5.6.1

Xcode 13.3   :      Swift version 5.6

Xcode 13.2   :      Swift version 5.5.2

Xcode 12.5   :      Swift version 5.4.2

Xcode 12.3   :      Swift version 5.3.2

Xcode 12.2   :      Swift version 5.3.1

Xcode 11.6   :      Swift version 5.2.4

Xcode 11.5   :      Swift version 5.2.4

Xcode 11.4   :      Swift version 5.2

Xcode 11.3   :      Swift version 5.1.3

Xcode 11.2.1 :      Swift version 5.1.2

Xcode 11.1   :      Swift version 5.1
```

Comment: Thank you. The terminal command was helpful because the version in my project was set to "Unspecified"

Answer (score 3):

I am using Swift from Google Colab. Here's how to check it in Colab.

```
!/swift/toolchain/usr/bin/swift --version
```

The result is `5.0-dev`

Answer (score 3):

Type in terminal

```
$ swift -v
```

Output in terminal

> Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53).

Comment: short and sweet

Comment: The help for `-v` says "Show commands to run and use verbose output" so this isn't really what OP is asking for even if the command includes a printout of the current version

Answer (score 2):

if you want to check the run code for a particular version of swift you can use

```
#if compiler(>=5.1) //4.2, 3.0, 2.0 replace whatever swft version you wants to check
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for how to find which version of Swift your project is using in a few click in **Xcode 12** to help out rookies like me.

1. Click on your Project (top level Blue Icon in the left hand pane)
2. Click on Build Settings (5th item in the Project > Header)
3. Scroll down to Swift Compiler - Language, and look at the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the version of the swift from the termianl by the following command:

`swift -version`.
You can also type `swift --help` to see more commands you can use with swift langauage on the terminal.

Another way to find and make sure that XCode is indeed using that same version of swift is to go to the project's build setting and check the *Swift Langauge version* under the **Swift Compiler - Language** section. Refer screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: The tip in the first part is fantastic TY

Answer (score -2):

By just entering `swift` command in the terminal, it will show the version, while logging to Swift console.(something like below)

```
System-IOSs-MacBook-Air swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7).
Type :help for assistance.
```

Comment: just FTR it no longer does that when you type "swift" per se

Answer (score -3):

Bonus contribution:
I'm using a custom node.js script to extract a clean string for use with Jazzy documentation. You might get some use of this if you can find a place to work it into your dev process:

Invoked from a Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
swiftversion=$(node SwiftVerSlicer.js "${xcrun swift -version}");
echo $swiftversion
```

SwiftVerSlicer.js:

```
// begin script
const inputString = `${process.argv[2]}`
let searchTerm = (inputString.indexOf('(') - 1)//-1 cause whitespace
let version = inputString.slice(0,searchTerm)
console.log(version)
// end script
```

You can also use regex of course, but do whatever you like :]

Answer (score -4):

1. Select your project
2. Build Setting
3. search for "swift language"
4. now you can see which swift version you are using in your project

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojn3m.png

Comment: How is that different from the first solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080904/1187415?

Comment: well i am going throw main project directory and when you type "swift language" it is only show swift version on top in Build Settings nothing other than that..