# Can't find Swift 5.2 in Xcode 11.4.1

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I can't see Swift 5.2 option in Build Settings, Xcode latest version 11.4.1 (11E503a)

[image: No Swift 5.2 option]

[image]

I ran `xcrun swift -version` and got this:

```
Apple Swift version 5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0
```

How can I get Swift 5.2 option?

Comment: See [this chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52819598/5133585) for what Swift version your version of Xcode supports. According to that chart, it doesn't actually support version 4 either, but version 4.1.50. Because it supports two 4.x versions, it needs to differentiate between them. On the other hand, it only supports one 5.x version, so it doesn't need to specify which.

Comment: There's nothing wrong to fix

Comment: Putting `xcrun swift -version` into the command line will tell you exact version

Comment: I ran xcrun swift -version and I got this: Apple Swift version 5.2.2