# How to change Swift version from 5 to 4 in Xcode?

Tags: swift

I am programming with Swift in Xcode (MacBook Air 2015) and I want to change my Swift version from 5 to 4. How to do that?

Comment: Perhaps this answer in the Apple exchange will help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181472/is-it-possible-to-select-which-version-of-swift-to-use-in-xcode

Comment: See [How do I see which version of Swift I'm using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790188/how-do-i-see-which-version-of-swift-im-using)

Comment: @rmaddy thanks man, that worked!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Project ► (Select Your Project Target) ► Build Settings ► (Type
> 'swift_version' in the Search bar) Swift Compiler Language ► Swift
> Language Version ► Click on Language list

Here you can change your version.

[image: An example screenshot]

Comment: What if this is a Swift Package?

Answer (score 1):

For SPMs you can do as follows:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "Foo",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Foo",
            targets: ["Foo"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Foo",
            dependencies: [])
    ],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [.version("5.7"))]
)
```

> `swiftLanguageVersions` is the version of the Swift language to use for compiling Swift sources in the package. The value is passed as-is to the Swift compiler's `-swift-version` flag.