# Swift version dropdown doesn't have latest version

Tags: swift, xcode

My Swift version on my mac:

```
$ swiftc -version 
Apple Swift version 5.3.2 (swiftlang-1200.0.45 clang-1200.0.32.28)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
```

However, when I try to change my project's Swift version to 5.3, there's no dropdown option for it:
[image]

Xcode version is 12.3

Comment: That’s how it’s supposed to be. Not every version is included, only major upgrades

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Swift 5.1 and 5.2 aren't major upgrades?

Comment: Notice that the version here means that version or higher

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "Swift Language Version" Xcode setting for? Because it still builds newer Swift code with an older version set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60177016/what-is-the-swift-language-version-xcode-setting-for-because-it-still-builds)