# Only run code if on a certain version of Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making a library that uses the [variants variable of AVAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avpartialasyncproperty/3821035-variants). That's less important; the significant part is that it has an Xcode 13+ requirement. This library may be used by apps running Xcode 12. Is there a compiler flag that can run code only if on a certain version of Xcode?

Something like how you would do this for a Swift version:

```
#if swift(>=5.0)
   // code
#else
   // code
#endif
```

I'd want to do

```
#if xcode(>=13.0)

   // use variants

#endif
```

Comment: XCode does not execute code by itself. You have to check for compiler version included in xCode or swift version that first appear in xCode 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `#if compiler(>=5.5)` works here. Note, this is different than `if swift(>=5.5)`, which will not necessarily work depending on the swift version you have set in your project.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there’s no way of directly checking the Xcode version. However, Xcode 13 supports iOS 15, [Xcode 12 doesn’t](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12_5_1-release-notes). You can use that as a workaround to check if Xcode version is 13 or higher.

```swift
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 150000 // iOS 15 or greater
// Xcode 12 will not see this code.
#else
// Xcode 12 and lower will see this
#endif
```

Comment: I believe this is for objective-c only, not swift

Answer (score 0):

[Actual Post Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62342723/9055350)

```
Xcode 12.5   :      Swift version 5.4.2

Xcode 12.3   :      Swift version 5.3.2

Xcode 12.2   :      Swift version 5.3.1

Xcode 11.6   :      Swift version 5.2.4

Xcode 11.5   :      Swift version 5.2.4

Xcode 11.4   :      Swift version 5.2

Xcode 11.3   :      Swift version 5.1.3

Xcode 11.2.1 :      Swift version 5.1.2

Xcode 11.1   :      Swift version 5.1
```

And then here's how to check:

```
#if compiler(>=5) //4.2, 3.0, 2.0 replace whatever swift version you wants to check
print("Hello Swift 5")
#endif
```

All the best