# Error to use a shorter spelling to unwrap a value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, option-type, unwrap

in Swift documentation at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html, there are examples about usage of optionals and unwrapping them. When I try the examples on my Macbook, I got an error as; **"Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer".**

**Defining the variables part in document:**

```
let nickname: String? = nil
let fullName: String = "John Appleseed"
let informalGreeting = "Hi \(nickname ?? fullName)"
```

**Explanation and example parts which throws the error written above:**

`You can use a shorter spelling to unwrap a value, using the same name for that unwrapped value.`

```
if let nickname {
    print("Hey, \(nickname)")
}
```

Why I cannot use `if let nickname` and if it throws error, why it is written in the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorthand syntax for optional unwrapping with `if let`, `guard let` and `while let` was introduced in `swift 5.7`. I believe u are using an older version of swift.

[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790188/how-do-i-see-which-version-of-swift-im-using) this to find out which version of swift u are using.

For more details [read](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-language-updates-from-wwdc22/) the section `Language updates` -> `Quality of life improvements`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
When I run the command `xcrun swift -version`
I have obtained the following output:
`swift-driver version: 1.45.2 Apple Swift version 5.6.1 (swiftlang-5.6.0.323.66 clang-1316.0.20.12)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx12.0`
So you are right, it is caused by older Swift version. Many thanks