# How to print out Swift's version in a program?

Tags: swift, swift2

I am limited to Xcode 6.2 if I am using Mavericks, and the following code:

```
let setOfNumbers: Set<Int> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

won't work.  So `Set` should only work in Swift 1.2 and above.  How do I print out what Swift version I am using in the program?  (just like `p RUBY_VERSION` if using Ruby)

Comment: Have tried typing `Swift -v` in a console (it may be slightly different )?

Comment: that's a command not found... it might be by another name or the command line tools is a different installation

Comment: Does `swift -h` bring up a help menu?

Comment: if `swift` is a command not found, then `swift -h` shouldn't bring up anything

Comment: You didn't specify if the flag wasn't found, or if the Swift command itself wasn't.

Comment: "command not found" is not the same as "flag not found"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way you can check in Terminal:

```
$ xcrun swift -version
```

It will gives you result.

Comment: yup, it is giving me 2 lines: `Swift version 1.1 (swift-600.0.57.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0`

Comment: on my Macbook 12 inch with Yosemite and XCode 6.4, it is giving me `Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.53.1 clang-602.0.53)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0`

Answer (score 7):

**Updated answer**

Starting with **Swift 2.2** (Xcode 7.3b) you *can* determine the Swift version and run code conditionnally with the `#if swift()` build configuration.

Example:

```
#if swift(>=2.2)
    print("Running Swift 2.2 or later")
#else
    print("Running Swift 2.1 or earlier")
#endif
```

The branch containing code for the compatible version of Swift will be executed, and the other branch will be *ignored*.

**Old answer**

There's no known way to do it in code ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862056/how-to-conditionally-compile-version-specific-swift-1-2-vs-2-0-code-in-the-sam?rq=1), [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140476/how-can-i-programmatically-find-swifts-version)).

You can do this in the Terminal:

```
swift -version
```

*For this command to be accurate you need to check that Xcode tools are linked to the proper Xcode version (can be confusing if you have Xcode and Xcode-beta installed side by side).*

Comment: your 2nd ref did it... `swift -version` won't work as I probably need to set up or install some command line tools first